# Server-sent events and php file. How to protect php?

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

Good afternoon. I am using SSE technology to replace the constant AJAX request to the database.
I have a page that opens a php file for server-sent events work.
The simplest code:

```
 var source = new EventSource("/path/test_live.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
    };
```

The php file is simple too:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
echo "retry: 5000\n";
........
foreach ($result as $item) {
 echo "data: ". $item['event']."\n";
 }
 echo "\n";
ob_flush();
flush();
```

Data is taken from the database every 5 seconds and transferred to the page. This all works great! Everything is fine. In the future, using SSE, I want to solve another problem. I want to learn how to do SSE not every N seconds, but only when a new event appears in the database. One file fills the table and, as soon as the value in it has changed to another, notify another php file about it, in which the function is already described above. But stop. I have a different problem and it prevents me from taking steps forward.

This file test_live.php can be opened simply by typing the address into the url. domain.com/path/test_live.php - and all data will open. This not only makes it meaningless to go to the home page, but can also provoke those who copy someone else's content. The data is shown in pure form.

How can php be protected by denying access to everyone except EventSource? I read a similar problem and they just suggest sending something on a GET \ POST request so that php could recognize it.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750760/eventsource-sse-server-sent-events-security for example here.

But how to transfer "this" to hide it and so that it would be impossible to open the php file with "this" on the direct url? Is it possible to solve this via php defined, .htaccess Order Deny, allow or using javascript itself? (for example, somehow encrypt the path?).
If this can be done through cookies, then how can php understand this and make everything secure? Or does the problem have no solution in principle?

*a day later and two cups of coffee*

**Finaly Update and my choice for solving the problem.**

I am using EventSource polyfill and post headers. In the php file I check getallheaders()

```
if (getallheaders()["Myheader"] === 'Varible') {
    MyFunction();
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    header('Location: 404-page.html');
}
```

Sorry for my English and hard to read text. But thanks for your attention.

Comment: what is "this"?

Comment: Add a nonce as a query parameter to the URL, and check this in the server code.

Answer (score 0):

Server Sent Events are just HTTP. So to protect your EventSource you should protect it as you would any other resource on your server. I am not a PHP developer so I cannot give you the details. However, if you make sure that the user is logged in prior to accessing the page that you are going to link to your EventSource, then you can use the same method to restrict access to it. If they are not authorised then the EventSource can return a `401` status code.