# How to create and identify multiple SSE-Streams in the Backend with Mern?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

i want to use server-side events (SSE) to send messages to the user, without the need to refresh the page on the frontend. I am using the MERN-Stack. Socket.io seems to "overloaded" and "to much" for my backend. So i think SSE should be fine.

I used for this the npm-package "express-sse".

I accomplished to create several SSE-Streams (for every userId one).

```
router.get(
  "/stream/:id",
  authenticateUser,
  authenticateSSE,
  sse.init
);
```

I will use as example as id: 6565

The user use this route and the id is his userId(6565), then the authenticateUser-Middleware, use the JSON Web Token, to add to the req.user his Id(6565).

Then the authenticateSSE-middleware checks if the userId(6565) in the route:id is the same that was added from the token.

Then if everything is correct sse.init starts the SSE-Stream on the route api/sse/stream/6565.

In the frontend i am able to use the route (only if the user has the right token).

So its safe. Another user withouth the token can't access this stream.

Now the problem:

In a controller (for example in *sendMessageToSingleUser*) i want to create a message on the server and after that i want to send per SSE the message "refetch your messages" to the user (with userId: 6565), who received the message.

So i want push with SSE a message through a specific stream ("api/sse/stream/6565"), to a specific event (listenForMessages) and only the single user which userId is 6565, should receive it.

BUT, in the controller i can only use

```
sse.send("refetch your messages", "listenForMessages")
```

This sends the message to ALL Streams.

How can i identify in the controller *sendMessageToSingleUser* only the SSE-Stream: 6565.

Something with the structure like:

```
sse("api/sse/stream/6565").send("refetch your messages", "listenForMessages")
```

Or i am understanding SSE completely wrong and you have only one stream open on the backend for all users? How to do you prevent that other users can't listen to messages for a single user? Only with different EventNames? What if someone just trying out to listen to a few eventnames and get lucky, to find a existing one (even if i would use with nanoid a "difficult to guess" name)?

In this thread: [EventSource / SSE (Server-Sent-Svents) - Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324657/eventsource-sse-server-sent-svents-security) :

It was called bad practice to have only one stream, instead it was suggested to have one stream per user (which would for my security a lot better!).

Thanks for your help.